# Question on confidence intervals for uniform distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, uniform-distribution

I have a random variable $X$ which is distributed uniformly over $[0,b]$. I want to know based on only one observation what is the confidence level of the interval $[X, 4X]$? I know this entails finding $P(X \leq b \leq 4X)$ but am entirely unsure how to approach the question. I have only had experience constructing confidence intervals for normally distributed variable and am very thrown off by the fact that $X$ is distributed uniformly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always the case that $X \leq b$, so you only need to find

\begin{align}
P(b \leq 4X) &= P(1/4 \leq X / b) \\
&= 1 - P(X / b < 1/4) \\
&= 1 - 1/4 \\
&= 3/4 
\end{align}

since $X / b \sim$ uniform$[0, 1]$.